Building Docker Images on Talos Kubernetes
The Problem
Currently I'm using the Gitlab kubernetes executor (Gitlab runner) to try and build custom docker images within a CI/CD pipeline. I have deployed my Gitlab runner via the official helm chart to my Talos kubernetes cluster running on my ProxMox homelab. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to build docker images while working with all the security rules built into Talos Linux.
What I've Tried
Following the Talos and Kubernetes documentation, I have added the pod-security.kubernetes.io/enforce=privileged label to the namespace where my Gitlab runner pods reside granting them elevated privileges (Assumingely). After this, we have to tackle the problem of dealing with the daemon/runtime. Talos linux does not install docker nor do they provide it as an optional extension in their image factory. With this said, mounting /var/run/docker.sock to the pods as a volume is out of the picture. Moving on, I've tried both buildah and podman as potential replacements because neither of which require access to a daemon or runtime in order to build docker images, however, no joy was being had because of a common issue/error every time I attempted to build an image or simply login to a remote registry:
Buildah:
Logging into Gitlab Container Registry...
Error during unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER): Operation not permitted
User namespaces are not enabled in /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces.
time="2024-10-03T05:01:30Z" level=error msg="parsing PID \"\": strconv.Atoi: parsing \"\": invalid syntax"
time="2024-10-03T05:01:30Z" level=error msg="(Unable to determine exit status)"

Podman:
podman build --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t registry.gitlab.com/infravise/foundation/warp-ci/staging/podman_ci:1479719347 -f docker/podman_ci/Dockerfile  .
time="2024-10-03T05:31:39Z" level=warning msg="\"/\" is not a shared mount, this could cause issues or missing mounts with rootless containers"
cannot clone: Operation not permitted
user namespaces are not enabled in /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces
Error: cannot re-exec process

Doing some research on both of these tools and their errors, all I could find were some pretty old Github chats talking about the same issue and no one really providing any adequate/useful solution that actually worked.
My cry to the ether is as such:
Does anyone know how to build docker images within pods running on Talos kubernetes? I don't care what technology/tool you used or what spell you had to cast to do so.

Don't know if it helps, but here are my 2 cents: That label pod-security.kubernetes.io/enforce=privileged will only allow you to run pods as priviledged but won't automatically make them priviledged. You still need to give them the "priviledged" annotation as in normal kubernetes.
Are you using a talos version that actually supports user namespaces? It seems they added support for it in 1.8.2
